# Sorry, Ubuntu 16.04 has experienced an internal error cannot fixed it with already mentioned methods

Tags: 16.04

[image]

I can not understand what is the problem for my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and how to fix it . Also while trying to upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 , it shows no enough space . Why this happens to me ? Please help.

Comment: Why did you tag as 14.04? Besides that you have a warning sign that usually means a problem with software sources. Better post the full error messages of `sudo apt update` and, of course, take care of the "not enough space" issue.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia  By using the command 'sudo apt updte' , we get some lines and at the end I find these ---- ** W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: The package cache file is corrupted
 **

Comment: Those "some lines" is what's important but don't bother now. Please read the duplicates mentioned above.